# adb sync shows Product directory not specified

Tags: adb

I am using android in an emulator integrated with eclipse. I was trying to import my gmail contacts into my emulator. For that purpose, I exported my gmail contacts to a .vcf file (contacts.vcf) from my gmail account. Then I used `adb push contacts.vcf /sdcard/contacts.vcf` to make it move into my emulator sdcard. And then, I used `adb sync` to sync the contacts with my emulator. Unfortunately, I got the following output: `adb sync showing product directory not specified`. Somebody help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

The `adb sync` command is for people to use while developing Android ROMs. The "product directory" mentioned is part of the Android source tree, and `adb sync` can only be used with a ROM you've compiled yourself.

It has nothing to do with syncing contacts or any other app data.

Answer (score 0):

Set your PRODUCT_OUT by exporting path as explained below:

Open `bashrc` from terminal

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Scroll to the bottom of the file and add ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT like this

```
export ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT= <PATH TO AOSP SOURCE>/out/target/product/<TARGET>
```

CTRL+X to Exit
Choose Yes when asking for an override

close the terminal and now it should work in a new terminal.

Comment: Note that this answer is only useful to solve the issue in the title regarding `adb sync` (if they have a need with this command), though this doesn't help in solving the background issue about syncing Gmail contacts to the emulator.